# %MY_VARIABLE% works in path on my laptop but not on windows server

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I use an environment variable to define the path for Java so I can change what version of Java I'm using (.bat file is shown at the end of this post).

The whole thing hinges on creating a %JAVA_VERSION% environment variable and then using that in the path.  This all works on my lap top.  When I use %JAVA_VERSION% in the Path environment variable it is correctly resolved to the value of the environment variable as shown below.

[image]

However, when I do this on an AWS EC2 instance, the %JAVA_VERSION% variable is not resolved as shown below and running "java" at a cmd prompt does not work.

[image]

Is there a way to get this to work on the Windows Server (details of the server shown below)

[image]

This is the .bat file used to switch Java versions:

```
:: ---
::
:: SCRIPT TO SET JAVA VERSION
::
:: ---

@echo off
echo.
echo.
if "%~1"=="" goto error 
if %1%==8 goto v8 
if %1%==11 goto v11

echo Valid Input Is:
echo   8
echo   11
echo.
:v8
    echo Setting Java Version to 1.8
    set JAVA_VERSION=C:\_YES\tools\java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin
    set JAVA_HOME="C:\_YES\tools\java\jdk1.8.0_261\
    setx JAVA_VERSION C:\_YES\tools\java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin
    setx JAVA_HOME C:\_YES\tools\java\jdk1.8.0_261\
    goto endif 

:v11
    echo Setting Java Version to 11.0.11
    set JAVA_VERSION=C:\_YES\tools\java\jdk-11.0.11\bin
    set JAVA_HOME="C:\_YES\tools\java\jdk-11.0.11\
    setx JAVA_VERSION C:\_YES\tools\java\jdk-11.0.11\bin
    setx JAVA_HOME C:\_YES\tools\java\jdk-11.0.11\
    goto endif 

:v1.17
    echo Setting Java Version to 1.17
    set JAVA_VERSION=C:\program_files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin
    set JAVA_HOME=C:\program_files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\
    setx JAVA_VERSION C:\program_files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin
    setx JAVA_HOME C:\program_files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\
    goto endif

:error 
    echo ! ! ! JAVA VERSION NOT SET ! ! ! 
    echo Java version must be 8 or 11
    goto endif 
    goto end 

:endif 
    set path=%JAVA_VERSION%;%PATH%

:end
echo Current JAVA_VERSION is %JAVA_VERSION%
@echo on
java -version
@echo off
echo.
echo.
echo Done.
echo.
echo.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by a quote character (") at the beginning of the JAVA_VERSION variable when the error was seen.  Similar to what was occurring in [ant error "The syntax of the command is incorrect." on running ant.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361995/ant-error-the-syntax-of-the-command-is-incorrect-on-running-ant-bat).